# How do I create a new iCloud account?

Tags: ipad, apple-id

Hi I would like to ask how do I create a new iCloud account for my iPad Mini. I forgot my old one. How can I do this?

Comment: Recovering it via https://iforgot.apple.com/ might be the easier way, did you try that already?

Answer (score 2):

Just visit https://appleid.apple.com/account on mobile Safari and fill in the required fields.
[image: apple id creation form]

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can do:

- Recover it using [iForgot](https://iforgot.apple.com/password/verify/appleid) using your email/security questions. This is the best thing to do if you forgot your password as it saves the hassle of creating a new one

Bear in mind you will need either your email or security questions available:

[image: reset]

**Note**:  If you forgot your security questions you need to use your email. To reset your security questions you will need your password.

- [Create a new Apple ID.](https://appleid.apple.com/account) Bear in mind all previous data will be lost and it will need to be setup again.

This includes Purchases and Purchase history, Music, any data stored in iCloud including Backups and Photos.